# The most efficient way to remove all characters in the 1st string from the 2nd string?

Tags: algorithm, string

I was asked about this question. I can only think of a O(nm) algorithm if n is the length of the 1st string and m is the length of the 2nd string.

Comment: Do you want to remove all characters, or all occurrences? e.g. should removing "AB" from "BABY" return "Y" or "BY"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do it in O(n + m). Just create a reference table showing whether character exists in first string. Something like this (pseudo-code in no particular language)

```
// fill the table
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    characterExists[a[i]] = true;
}

// iterate over second string
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    if !characterExists[b[i]] {
        // remove char (or do whatever else you want)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [Boyer-Moore String Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)?

> The worst-case to find all occurrences
>   in a text needs approximately 3*N
>   comparisons, hence the complexity is
>   O(n), regardless whether the text
>   contains a match or not. This
>   proof took some years to determine. In
>   the year the algorithm was devised,
>   1977, the maximum number of
>   comparisons was shown to be no more
>   than 6*N; in 1980 it was shown to be
>   no more than 4*N, until Cole's result
>   in Sep 1991.

C implementation:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALPHABET_SIZE (1 << CHAR_BIT)

static void compute_prefix(const char* str, size_t size, int result[size]) {
    size_t q;
    int k;
    result[0] = 0;

    k = 0;
    for (q = 1; q < size; q++) {
        while (k > 0 && str[k] != str[q])
            k = result[k-1];

        if (str[k] == str[q])
            k++;
        result[q] = k;
    }
}

static void prepare_badcharacter_heuristic(const char *str, size_t size,
        int result[ALPHABET_SIZE]) {

    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
        result[i] = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result[(size_t) str[i]] = i;
}

void prepare_goodsuffix_heuristic(const char *normal, size_t size,
        int result[size + 1]) {

    char *left = (char *) normal;
    char *right = left + size;
    char reversed[size+1];
    char *tmp = reversed + size;
    size_t i;

    /* reverse string */
    *tmp = 0;
    while (left < right)
        *(--tmp) = *(left++);

    int prefix_normal[size];
    int prefix_reversed[size];

    compute_prefix(normal, size, prefix_normal);
    compute_prefix(reversed, size, prefix_reversed);

    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        result[i] = size - prefix_normal[size-1];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        const int j = size - prefix_reversed[i];
        const int k = i - prefix_reversed[i]+1;

        if (result[j] > k)
            result[j] = k;
    }
}
/*
 * Boyer-Moore search algorithm
 */
const char *boyermoore_search(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
    /*
     * Calc string sizes
     */
    size_t needle_len, haystack_len;
    needle_len = strlen(needle);
    haystack_len = strlen(haystack);

    /*
     * Simple checks
     */
    if(haystack_len == 0)
        return NULL;
    if(needle_len == 0)
        return haystack;

    /*
     * Initialize heuristics
     */
    int badcharacter[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    int goodsuffix[needle_len+1];

    prepare_badcharacter_heuristic(needle, needle_len, badcharacter);
    prepare_goodsuffix_heuristic(needle, needle_len, goodsuffix);

    /*
     * Boyer-Moore search
     */
    size_t s = 0;
    while(s <= (haystack_len - needle_len))
    {
        size_t j = needle_len;
        while(j > 0 && needle[j-1] == haystack[s+j-1])
            j--;

        if(j > 0)
        {
            int k = badcharacter[(size_t) haystack[s+j-1]];
            int m;
            if(k < (int)j && (m = j-k-1) > goodsuffix[j])
                s+= m;
            else
                s+= goodsuffix[j];
        }
        else
        {
            return haystack + s;
        }
    }

    /* not found */
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This algorithm does something complete unrelated?